# Can't get Rails return value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails method that just returns a string, and for some reason, I can't seem to get the `success` return value in the JavaScript.

```
def count
  render :nothing => true
  return "success"
end

$.post("/home/count",
  function(data) {
    document.getElementById("test_call_button").value = 'Calling...' + count;
  });
```

The object that is returned by `$.post("/home/count");` has a `responseText` of `" "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of a controller action is not sent back to the requester; what you render is, and in this case you're specifically rendering `:nothing`.

If you want to see the result in your javascript, change your render line to

```
render :text => 'success'
```

I would urge you to render a json object as your response though, which makes it trivial to add other fields in the future should they be necessary.

Also make sure to check out the [Rails rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).